# Custom url rewrite help needed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have created a database with url slug and it contains urls like `mysite.com/blog/content/user1` and blog is folder where file is so I want to change `mysite.com/blog/page.php?name=content&user=user1` to `mysite.com/blog/content/user1` how can I do that I have tried

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ page.php?name=$1&user=$2` but that doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/([^//]+)/([^//]+)$ blog/page.php?name=$1&user=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Please avoid making the slug record using `/` which means the uri segment better to use `-` for you slug so if your url is something `mysite.com/blog/page.php?name=content&user=user-a` and you want to show like `mysite.com/blog/content/user-a` them above rule will also work for that url aso

Comment: It worked thanks. Can you tell me how can I rewrite if slug is test/me ?

Comment: Can you brief about your slug rewrite issue ??

Comment: I mean as I said I have a column called slug that is used for url and poster can manually add slug like test-a or test/a so how can I show test/a like `mysite.com/blog/content/test/a `